# Rules- How can I copy the formatted text in one field to another?

Tags: rules

I need to move the values of a field (long text and summary) to another field (long text and  summary).  I am trying to do this with Rules and VBO.

I have fetched nodes A and B, and I want to set the value of the field in B to the value of the field in A.

The challenge is that I can't use the *Set a data value* action to simply set B to A.  I can use Rules to create a *text* variable and get the value from A that way, but I still can't set that *text* variable as the value (Rules requires a *formatted text* variable).  However, if I try to create a *formatted text* variable, I can't set the value of the *Long text and summary* field as the value.

I have the two nodes available in Rules and they both have fields of type *Long text and summary*.  I just want to set the value of B to the value of A.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out-- I needed to add :value after the body field, since the field value contains the summary, text format, and text value.

So for example, instead of *profile:field-myfield*, use *profile:field-myfield:value*.